# Oracle SQL - hour slabs

Tags: sql, oracle, hour

I have the following data:

CUSTOMER_ORDERS:

```
CUST_ORDER_NO CREATE_DATETIME
WEB904204965    17-SEP-21 03.12.45.719000000 PM
WEB904204966    17-SEP-21 03.16.45.719000000 PM
```

I want to check the number of orders in every hour, like:

```
COUNT SLAB
2     1-2 PM
4     2-3 PM
```

How to write the query for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `trunc` the date/time or extract just the `hour` component, then `GROUP BY` that expression.

Here's a test case with sample SQL:

[Working Test Case with a little data](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=88eee52bfc6e6462d024433a08d9f2e5)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS n
     , to_char(dt, 'HH') AS slab
  FROM test
 GROUP BY to_char(dt, 'HH')
;
```

Result:

[image]

We could have used 'HH24' to show the 24 hour value or 'HH AM' to show the 'hours plus AM/PM' indicator.

`SELECT to_char(current_date, 'HH24') AS slab FROM dual;`

`SELECT to_char(current_date, 'HH AM') AS slab FROM dual;`

Comment: Your explanation and your code do not match.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Which part?  The example extracts the hour component with an expression (`to_char`) and groups by that expression.  The question only shows hours as the group, so I didn't just `trunc` the date/time value.  The test case uses its own data, and current_date, so the hours in the result will be based on the time you execute the test case.  The important detail is about the expression / grouping, whichever we decide to use.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I could have used 'HH24' or added the AM/PM indicator.

Comment: . . You explain `trunc()` but then use a different function in the code.

Comment: @GordonLinoff No problem. To be clear, I described two methods, both `trunc` and the extract method (which was done with `to_char`), but chose the second approach because of the OPs question, which didn't show any evidence of a date component in the result.  In the test case (fiddle), I decided to show both methods.